# I want to get Instance of web driver and use it

Tags: c#

Okay, guys! I changed my code and I want to give more specific question.

I want to run my `GetInformation()` as a loop as many times, as possible.

If values will not be available at web site, I want to run `AnotherFunction()`

How can I run `GetInformation()` with the instance of web driver? I am not confident in OOP, but I want to start my browser just one time and then get unstatic information from web site.
Web browser has to be run only one time.

```
     namespace Parser
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string CommandName1;
        public static string CommandName2;
        public static string Command1Goals;
        public static string Command2Goals;
        public static string TimeOfGame; //timer eeeeeeeee
        public static int TotalGoals;
        public static bool GameIsRun = true;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var driver = GetDriver();
            GetInformation(driver);
        }

        public static ChromeDriver GetDriver()
        {
            return new ChromeDriver();
        }

        public static void CheckGame()
        {
            var driver = GetDriver();
            while (GameIsRun)
            {
                GetInformation(GetDriver());
            }
        }

        static void GetInformation(ChromeDriver driver)
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://m.favorit.com.ua/uk/live/events/13931514/");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            CommandName1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='react-root']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/header/div[2]/span[1]")).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
            CommandName2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='react-root']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/header/div[2]/span[2]")).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
            Command1Goals = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='react-root']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/header/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]")).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
            Command2Goals = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='react-root']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/header/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]")).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
            TimeOfGame = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div/div/div//div/div[@class='headroom-wrapper']/div//div[3]/div")).GetAttribute("innerHTML"); ; //timer eeeeeeeee
            TotalGoals = Convert.ToInt32(Command1Goals) + Convert.ToInt32(Command2Goals);
            Console.WriteLine("Time: " + TimeOfGame + " \t\t|Total Goals: " + TotalGoals);
            Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            Console.WriteLine("Team 1: " + CommandName1 + " \t|Goals: " + Command1Goals);
            Console.WriteLine("Team 2: " + CommandName2 + " \t|Goals: " + Command2Goals);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }

        public static void AnotherFunction()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Can someone fix my code" is mighty vague. "I don't want to Google chrome starts many times" is alarming but unclear. What is `By`? What's actually going wrong? I can't make any sense out of the whole thing. Please put more effort into helping us help you. You want to provide enough information that the only thing we need to figure out is the one little point that has you stumped. If we're scratching our heads trying to figure out what your problem even is, you didn't help us enough. BTW, I didn't downvote you.

Comment: Tell us what you are trying to achieve, try make it as easy as possible for people to help you. They are doing it out of their kindness, so the least question askers can do is explain the problem. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There is a clear path to infinite recursion in your code. You need a base case to stop the recursion into the CheckGame() and GetInformation() methods. Perhaps you should remove the call to CheckGame() from within the GetInformation() method, and change the logic in CheckGame() to handle retries differently.

Comment: I want to get opportunities to use my driver in another Class , without starting it again. I want to my Browser starts just one time, and then I will be able to GetInformation() again and again.

Comment: I am sorry, I just think that my code is really easy. My apologizes

Comment: Okay, I will change my code! How can I repost it again or better way is to create new ticket ?

Comment: I changed my code, please help me with an instance. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do here is follow some good OOP principles and make your methods do just one thing.

You want one method that will instantiate your chrome Driver() object and return it and then you're GetInformation needs a parameter to have the driver passed in.

Something like this (I've left most of your code out as it would just be noise)

```
public static ChromeDriver GetDriver()
{
    return new ChromeDrive();
}

public static GetInformation(ChromeDriver driver)
{
    ...all the code you had before but without creating the driver object
}
```

then In check game we can do

```
var driver = GetDriver();
while(GameIsRun)
{
    GetInformation(driver);
}
```

Someone has mentioned in the comments that you are probably going to come up against some infinite looping problems, but you haven't really been clear how you want your program to work, so I can help you with that without more info

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. I changed my code with your advices. Can you please check it again? I am not confident in OOP, and I dont know how to use instance of driver.

Comment: @TheVee you need to pass the return value of GetDriver() into your GetInformation method. There are 2 ways of doing this. Store it in a local variable `var driver = GetChromeDriver(); GetInformation(driver);` or just pass the result of the method call into the GetInformation method like such `GetInformation(GetChromeDriver());`

Comment: Don't take this the wrong but it might be worth looking in to some of the basics of the C# language and doing some beginner stuff about methods and classes etc

Comment: Yes, I just starting to learn C# and I decided to do code. Thus I collided with issues.

Comment: @TheVee Its good to make something that you find useful and interesting, I think it helps the learning processing. But don't run before you can walk

Comment: Yep, I absolutely agree with you. I changed my code again. Please, give me another hint and I will realize how it works, it helps me a lot to understand instances.

Comment: this bit of code `static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                GetInformation();
            }` needs to read 
           `static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var driver = GetDriver();
                GetInformation(driver );
            }'

Comment: thanks a lot , I have some time to check it, but I changed code here !